# How to predict the next image in a sequence, or predict the deblurring of an image?

Tags: image-processing, data-compression

I have 3 versions of an image at lower resolutions - 480p, 720p, and 1080p. Is it possible to use those 3 images to predict the next highest resolution image (the 4k image)?

My first guess was that I could calculate the difference (or momentum or acceleration?) of each pixel between images and use that to predict the new 4th image. I assume this would require me to give all pictures the same number of pixels. I also assume that the differences in each pixel between images would need to be smooth. Would this work?

My other guess was that maybe there is some kind of statistics or machine learning technique that I could use, but I don't know anything about that stuff.

Thanks!

Ps - this man is not my real data. My real images are an intensity map (temperatures over an area) at different resolutions. I suspect that the introduction of colors might complicate things, so should we pretend that the images below are black-and-white images?

Here are the pictures:
[image: Luther at different resolutions]

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't create information out of nothing.  There's no magic.  There's not enough information in the three lower-res to uniquely determine the high-res image.

Of course, you can always upscale an image, but that won't make it any higher quality or sharper than what you started with.

Note that "4K" is a marketing term, not a precise specification of an image resolution.  There are multiple different resolutions that are all marketed as "4K".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution.